# how can we identify notepad file?

Tags: notepad

how can we identify notepad files which is created in two computer, is there a any way to get any information about in which computer it was created.Or whether it is build in xp or linux.

Comment: Notepad is designed to edit files comprising of plain ascii or unicode text.. there is no way to reliably determine if such a file was created in said application.  You could examine new line characters to make a determination if the file was created on windows or linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the file, you should be able to see the permissions and attributes of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check at the end of the line. Under GNU/Linux lines end with \n (ascii: 0x0A) while under Miscrosoft W$ndos it is \r\n (ascii: 0x0D 0x0A).

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 0):

found this: http://bit.ly/J258Mr

for identifying a word document but some of the info is relevant

> To see on which computer the document had been created, open the Word
>   document in a hex editor and look for "PID_GUID". This is followed by
>   a globally unique identifier that, depending upon the version of Word
>   used, may contain the MAC address of the system on which the file was
>   created.
>
> Checking the user properties (as already mentioned) is a good way to
>   see who the creator of the original file was...so, if the document was
>   not created from scratch and was instead originally created on another
>   system, then the user information will be for the original file.
>
> Another way to locate the "culprit" in this case is to parse the
>   contents of the NTUSER.DAT files for each user on each computer. While
>   this sounds like a lot of work, it really isn't...b/c you're only
>   looking for a couple of pieces of information. Specifically, you're
>   interested in the MRU keys for the version of Word being used, as well
>   as perhaps the RecentDocs keys."

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I can think on the top of my mind is inspecting the newline characters on your file - I'm assuming your files do have multiple lines. If the file was generated using Windows then a newline would be characterized by the combination of carriage return and line feed characters (CR+LF) whereas a simple line feed (LF) would be a hint that the file was generated in a Linux machine.

Answer (score -1):

Right click one the file--> Details . You can see the computer name where it was created and the date.